# Python3 When printing CR and some text, the text is not erased

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing, progress

I am trying to write code for progressing.
When I print CR, it just move the cursor to the beginning, but the text remains.
like below:

```
print('xxxxx', end='\r')
print('yy')  # I want to print only 'yy'
>> yyxxx
```

Can I delete text, not just move the cursor?

Comment: Can you add what your expected output is?

Comment: Your piece of code prints "yy" for me.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a terminal that understands ANSI escape sequences (which is most common terminals), you can use the following:

```
print('xxxxx', end='\r')
print('yy\x1b[K')
```

The `\x1b[K` sequence instructs the terminal to erase from the cursor to the end of the line.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to chepner's answer but maybe a bit more understandable for readers of the code not familiar with [ANSI control characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code)

```
CURSOR_UP_ONE = "\x1b[1A"
ERASE_LINE = "\x1b[2K"

print("xxxxx")
print(CURSOR_UP_ONE + ERASE_LINE + "yy")
```

If you don't like to hardcode these, they're available in the popular 3rd party lib [colorama](https://github.com/tartley/colorama/blob/v0.3.4/colorama/ansi.py#L36-L46):

```
>>> import colorama  # pip install colorama
>>> colorama.ansi.clear_line()
'\x1b[2K'
>>> colorama.ansi.Cursor.UP()
'\x1b[1A'
```